# How to write a jquery plugin that works with multiple elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm having trouble with jQuery scope, I think. I'm experimenting with the classic jquery "greenify" tutorial plugin, and have adapted it to change the colour of all anchor links to the colour specified by their respective data-color attribute. However, the colour is always red. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<a data-color="red">Red</a>
<a data-color="yellow">Yellow</a>
<a data-color="black">Black</a>
```

JS:

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.colify = function() {
        this.css( "color", $(this).data('color') );
        return this;
    };
}( jQuery ));
$('a').colify();
```

JS FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/y4589gy2/

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggeset:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.colify = function () {
        // return the results of calling the methods for chaining,
        // note that 'this' refers to the jQuery collection (not DOM nodes):
        return this.css("color", function () {
            // using the anonymous function available to 'css()',
            // this here refers to the individual DOM node over
            // which jQuery is iterating in CSS():
            return $(this).data('color');

        });
    }
})(jQuery);
$('a').colify();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/y4589gy2/2/).

Although you don't need to invoke jQuery, or use `data()`, within the `css()` call, you could simply use `HTMLElement.dataset` to access the `data-*` attributes:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.colify = function () {
        return this.css("color", function () {
            // this.dataset.color returns the attribute value from 'data-color',
            // if that returns undefined (or a falsey value) 'black' is used instead:
            return this.dataset.color || 'black';

        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/y4589gy2/3/).

Or `this.getAttribute('data-color')` could be used (which is likely useful to support older browsers) in place of `this.dataset.color` ([JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/y4589gy2/4/)).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset).
  - [`Element..getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute).
- jQuery:

  - [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
  - [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Thats interesting, I never knew that you could pass a function as the second parameter of the CSS method. After some more research I found that for larger plugins, I could get the desired result by starting the plugin with the lines: `(function ( $ ) {
 
    $.fn.myplugin = function( options ) {

        
  return this.each( function() { // The rest of the plugin code here... }); 
    };
}( jQuery ));`